# Highchart: add custom button to show/hide annotations?

Tags: highcharts, annotations

i am using highchart to display a line chart. I have added some annotations.

```
annotations: [{
                            labels: [
        
        {
            point: {
                x: 1,
                y: 13.120689655172,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            },
            text: '(+) New Line First'
        },
        
        {
            point: {
                x: 8,
                y: 16.1,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            },
            text: '(+) Sold Some Books'
        },],
```

I like to create a button to show/hide these annotations. Can somebody help me?
I dont know how to create a button and to show hide them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepared a demo with the custom button which hides/shows the annotations.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/75gmt0v3/

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
  if (chart.annotationVisible) {
    chart.annotations[0].graphic.hide();
    chart.annotationVisible = false;
  } else {
    chart.annotations[0].graphic.show();
    chart.annotationVisible = true;
  }
})
```

If you want to render this button as a part of the chart use the `SVGRenderer` tool - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button